# Wrapping an image around a video ( responsive )

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to wrap a laptop image around a youtube video. I allready got a solution for that. Now i want to make everything responsive for smaller devices. Any solutions for that ?

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
#tv_container {
  background: url('img/video.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
  width: 1440px; /* Adjust TV image width */
  height: 810px; /* Adjust TV image height */
  position: relative;
}
#tv_container iframe {
  position: absolute;

}
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: relative;
  top: 78px;
  left: 252px;
  width: 65%;
  height: 67%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="tv_container">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <iframe width="760" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qidS1nnK0Ps" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the `@media` selectors, and instead of using `px`, use percents for the elements you wish to have responsive (inside the media selectors) `%`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `#tv_container` styles to use a variable width:

```
#tv_container {
    background: url('img/video.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

I also used an `auto` height for the container so it changes according to its width.